# roots of $\tan z = a z $

Tags: complex-analysis

Using [Rouche's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem) prove that $\tan z = az$ has:

1. infinitely many roots;
2. only two purely imaginary roots if $0< a< 1$;
3. all real roots if $a \ge 1$.

What do I take $f(x)$ and what do I take $g(x)$ (in general) for showing infinitely many roots and purely imaginary roots? I basically know showing finite roots within some region $|z| = a$

Also I think we can deduce with $\displaystyle \arctan z = \frac{1}{2i} \log \left( \frac{1 - iz}{1 + iz}\right) $ but how can it get it from Rouche's theorem?

Comment: Are you sure 2nd is true if $z>\pi/2$

Comment: @exploringnet I am not so sure, but the book claims it to be and it must have to be done using Rouche theorem.